Spring AI OpenAI Chat - Error while extracting response for type [OpenAiApi$ChatCompletion] and content type [application/json]
In my Spring Boot (3.3.4) app I am trying to use Spring AI OpenAI. I am completely new to this.
This is my setup:
application.properties
spring.ai.openai.api-key=key
spring.ai.openai.chat.options.model=gpt-4o-mini
spring.ai.openai.chat.options.temperature=0.3

build.gradle
ext {
    set('springAiVersion', "1.0.0-M2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.ai:spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.ai:spring-ai-bom:${springAiVersion}"
    }
}

TestClient
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TestClient {

    private final OpenAiChatModel openAiChatModel;

    public OpenAiResponseDto test(String query) {
        var outputConverter = new BeanOutputConverter<>(OpenAiResponseDto.class);
        var jsonSchema = outputConverter.getJsonSchema();
        Prompt prompt = new Prompt(getPrompt(query),
                OpenAiChatOptions.builder()
                        .withModel(OpenAiApi.ChatModel.GPT_4_O_MINI)
                        .withResponseFormat(new OpenAiApi.ChatCompletionRequest.ResponseFormat(OpenAiApi.ChatCompletionRequest.ResponseFormat.Type.JSON_SCHEMA, jsonSchema))
                        .build());
        ChatResponse response = openAiChatModel.call(prompt);
        String content = response.getResult().getOutput().getContent();
        return outputConverter.convert(content);
    }
}

OpenAiResponseDto
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Builder
public record OpenAiResponseDto(
        @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "firstFeield")
        String firstFeield,
        @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "secondField")
        String secondField,
        @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "thirdField")
        String thirdField,
        @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "fourthField")
        String fourthField
) {
}

I am constantly getting the following error:
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [org.springframework.ai.openai.api.OpenAiApi$ChatCompletion] and content type [application/json]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient.readWithMessageConverters(DefaultRestClient.java:237) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultResponseSpec.readBody(DefaultRestClient.java:694) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultResponseSpec.toEntityInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:664) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultResponseSpec.toEntity(DefaultRestClient.java:653) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.api.OpenAiApi.chatCompletionEntity(OpenAiApi.java:985) ~[spring-ai-openai-1.0.0-M2.jar:1.0.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.OpenAiChatModel.lambda$call$1(OpenAiChatModel.java:224) ~[spring-ai-openai-1.0.0-M2.jar:1.0.0-M2]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:344) ~[spring-retry-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-retry-2.0.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.OpenAiChatModel.lambda$call$3(OpenAiChatModel.java:224) ~[spring-ai-openai-1.0.0-M2.jar:1.0.0-M2]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.13.4.jar:1.13.4]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.OpenAiChatModel.call(OpenAiChatModel.java:221) ~[spring-ai-openai-1.0.0-M2.jar:1.0.0-M2]
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:406) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:354) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient.readWithMessageConverters(DefaultRestClient.java:213) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:697) ~[jackson-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:512) ~

What could be the issue here and how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

By calling OpenAI API with RestClient I realized I am always getting { as a response string. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

RESOLVED:
Apparently, there was a conflict with the following dependency:
io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager
Removing it fixed my issue.
